# how to add subtract divide and multiply columns on a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, operation

i hope you can help me.
i need to get this result:
for item in each row, create Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr column with result:

> df['Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr'] = [df['Max(In/Out Util)']/100*df['Egress
>   Speed']] / [df['Egress Speed']-(df['Egress Speed']/df['Oper. Member
>   Count'])]*100

Original DataFrame

```
Site Name           Oper. Member Count  Egress Speed    Max(In/Out Util)
KB201_XXX71_SR7                     2       6000000             11,1527 
KB201_XXX71_SR7                     2           N/A                 N/A 
KN092_XXX71_SR7                     4       4000000             9,60783
```

FinalDataFrame

```
Site Name           Oper. Member Count  Egress Speed    Max(In/Out Util)    Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr
KB201_XXX71_SR7                     2       6000000             11,1527                     22,3
KB201_XXX71_SR7                     2           N/A                 N/A                     N/A
KN092_XXX71_SR7                     4       4000000             9,60783                     12,8
```

Comment: that is literally `df['col4']=(df.col1+df.col2)/df.col3` ?

Comment: yes, but the name of columns are generic in this example.. I will give you a real example

Comment: i have edited my post with the real case

Comment: Can you add parenthesis in your equation?

Comment: @anky_91 solution does use the dot notation shortcut that will not work with complex column naming.  Use `df['column name']` notation.

Comment: @ScottBoston agreed :)

Comment: @ScottBoston what´s your idea? can you explain me more? thanks!!

Comment: Can you please put the expected number instead of "result" in the `final dataframe`? Otherwise I can't try and match my numbers with your expected output.

Comment: Please use multiple parenthesis, not brackets I am finally making sense of your formula...

Comment: Check my answer, it should work now.

Answer (score 3):

All you need to do is set up the math formula to express the result with the name of the columns:

```
   df['col4'] = (df['col1']+df['col2'])/df['col3']
```

EDIT: Newly requested formula:

```
df['Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr'] = [df['Max(In/Out Util)']/100*df['Egress Speed']] / [df['Egress Speed']-(df['Egress Speed']/df['Oper. Member Count'])]*100
```

EDIT2: Based on the fact your numbers are coded with Latin notation (this is, commas being used to symbolize decimal places) you should start by using:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.replace(',','.'))
df['Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr'] = df['Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr'].astype(int)
df['Egress Speed'] = df['Egress Speed'].astype(int)
df['Oper. Member Count'] = df['Oper. Member Count'].astype(int)
```

And then your proposed formula:

```
df['Max(In/Out Util)-1Mbr'] = (df['Max(In/Out Util)']*df['Egress Speed']) / (df['Egress Speed'] - df['Egress Speed'] / df['Oper. Member Count'])
```

Just use the final formula and it should work.

Comment: You are misusing brackets instead of parenthesis

Comment: Using the final formula, it gives me an error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'int'

Comment: Are all your columns integers/floats?

Comment: This is because the datatype of the Egress and Max columns are strings instead of numbers.  You need to use `pd.to_numeric` on those columns first, but first you need to remove the commas.

Comment: True, he is using Latin notation where commas are used to represent decimal places in numbers .

Answer (score 1):

It's just:

```
df['col4']= (df['col1']+df['col2'])/df['col3']
```

Comment: Careful with the formula as it is read as df['col4'] = a + b/c